# Print sorted (ascending) floating data with each index included

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

There are many approaches to locating peaks. Consider an array of data x[]. For our project, we define a peak as an element of the array that is a local maximum, greater than each of its neighbors by a factor of 2 or more. The first and last elements in an array have only one neighbor each, and by definition cannot be peaks. Hence, given this array x[] with 20 elements:

0.20 0.50 0.10 0.15 0.20 0.13 0.30 0.25 0.30 0.30 (elements 0-9)

0.70 0.20 0.45 0.15 0.20 0.85 0.30 0.65 0.20 0.10 (elements 10-19)

The peaks are at x[1] = 0.5, x[10] = 0.7, x[12] = 0.45, x[15] = 0.85, x[17] = 0.65.

For this project, you will write a program that scans through an array of data, finds the peaks based on the criterion defined above, and (for extra credit) sorts them into ascending order. Here’s what you program should do:

Declare and initialize an array x[] of 20 floats.

float [] x = {0.2f, 0.5f, 0.1f, 0.15f, 0.2f, 0.13f, 0.3f, 0.25f, 0.3f, 0.3f,
0.7f, 0.2f, 0.45f, 0.15f, 0.2f, 0.85f, 0.3f, 0.65f, 0.2f, 0.1f};

Print the elements of x[], 10 on each line, with a precision of 2 decimal places.

Locate the peaks in x[] and store their indices in an array called peaks[].

Print the index and data for each peak, in the order they appear in x[].

So far my code looks like:

```
    float[] x = {0.2f, 0.5f, 0.1f,  0.15f, 0.2f, 0.13f, 0.3f, 0.25f, 0.3f, 0.3f,
                 0.7f, 0.2f, 0.45f, 0.15f, 0.2f, 0.85f, 0.3f, 0.65f, 0.2f, 0.1f};

    int numPeaks = 0;   // Amount of peaks found.
    int[] peaks = new int[x.length];

    System.out.println("Data array:");  // Print header.

    // Print out data.
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%.2f ", x[i]);
        if (i == (x.length - 1) / 2) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n");   // Double line break.

    // Search for peaks and stores them into peaks[i].
    // Also counts how many peaks there are.
    for (int i = 1; i < x.length - 1; i++) {
        if (x[i] > (x[i-1] * 2) && x[i] > (x[i+1] * 2)) {
            numPeaks++;
            peaks[i] = i;
        }
    }
    // Print number of peaks found.
    System.out.println(numPeaks + " peaks found:");

    // Print only the peaks found along with their indices.
    for (int i = 1; i < x.length - 1; i++) {
        if (x[i] > (x[i-1] * 2) && x[i] > (x[i+1] * 2)) {
            System.out.printf("%2d", peaks[i]);
            System.out.println(" " + x[i]);
        }
    }
```

and the output:

```
Data array:
0.20 0.50 0.10 0.15 0.20 0.13 0.30 0.25 0.30 0.30 
0.70 0.20 0.45 0.15 0.20 0.85 0.30 0.65 0.20 0.10 

5 peaks found:
 1 0.5
10 0.7
12 0.45
15 0.85
17 0.65
```

and I want the output to look like this:

```
Data array:
0.20 0.50 0.10 0.15 0.20 0.13 0.30 0.25 0.30 0.30
0.70 0.20 0.45 0.15 0.20 0.85 0.30 0.65 0.20 0.10

5 peaks found:
 1 0.5
10 0.7
12 0.45
15 0.85
17 0.65

Sorted peaks:
12 0.45
 1 0.5
17 0.65
10 0.7
15 0.85
17 0.65
```

I just can't seem to get the element indices to be attached to the sorted floating data correctly. Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

If there is any information I am missing please just ask

Comment: While homework questions are technically on-topic on Stack Overflow, they are __very frowned upon__.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to sort you `peaks` array using a comparison that compares values in the original data.

If you are using Java 8 you could you `Integer` objects rather than `int` and then use a comparator:

```
Integer[] peaks;
Arrays.sort(peaks, Comparator.comparing(i -> x[i]));
```

You can do the same thing in Java 7 but you need to create your own comparator.